# Sklearn: find mean centroid location for clusters?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, scipy
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text as text
from sklearn import decomposition

descs = ["You should not go there", "We may go home later", "Why should we do your chores", "What should we do"]

vectorizer = text.CountVectorizer()

dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(descs).toarray()

vocab = np.array(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

nmf = decomposition.NMF(3, random_state = 1)

topic = nmf.fit_transform(dtm)
```

Printing `topic` leaves me with:

```
>>> print(topic)
[0.       , 1.403    , 0.     ],
[0.       , 0.       , 1.637  ],
[1.257    , 0.       , 0.     ],
[0.874    , 0.056    , 0.065  ]
```

Which are vectors of each element in `descs`'s likelihood to belong to a certain cluster. How can I get the coordinates of the centroid of each cluster? Ultimately, I want to develop a function to calculate the distance of each element in `descs` from the centroid of the cluster it was assigned to.

Would it be best to just compute the average of each `descs` element's `topic` value for each cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html) of `sklearn.decomposition.NMF` explain how to get the coordinates of the centroid of each cluster:

> **Attributes:**     **components_** : array, [n_components, n_features]
>                               Non-negative components of the data.

The basis vectors are arranged row-wise, as shown in the following interactive session:

```
In [995]: np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

In [996]: nmf.components_
Out[996]: 
array([[ 0.54,  0.91,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.89,  0.  ,  0.89,  0.37,  0.54,  0.  ,  0.54],
       [ 0.  ,  0.01,  0.71,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.71,  0.72,  0.71,  0.01,  0.02,  0.  ,  0.71,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.01,  0.61,  0.61,  0.61,  0.61,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.62,  0.02,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]])
```

As for your second question, I don't see the point of "*computing the average of each* `descs` *element's topic value for each cluster*". In my opinion it makes more sense to perform the classification through the calculated likelihoods.

Comment: I assume you created three centroids. How are the  coordinates of each centroid represented by each element in `nmf.components_`? The number of non-zero elements in that array seems to indicate high dimensionality.

Comment: The dimensions of `nmf.components_` are 3 rows by 14 columns, which correspond to 3 clusters and 14 different words, i.e. the vectors representing cluster centroids are linear combinations of the vocabulary basis.

Comment: So how could I find the x-y coordinates of the centroids themselves? Or is that a misguided ask?

Comment: The centroids are 14-dimensional vectors, they do not lie in a 2D space

Comment: Ah, I see. The values in the vectors indicate the coordinates for each dimension for each centroid. Thanks!